# How can I upload the table data from local database to cloud service?

Tags: mysql, cloud, mysql-python

I want to upload the database from local to cloud services like aws.
I have successfully created the database and tables and columns in cloud database from local database, but not able to transfer the data.

I have tried using outfile and infile command using python but getting an error

```py
mycursor3.execute("SELECT * FROM %s INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/test.csv' "% (tb[0]))
sqlformula="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test.csv' INTO TABLE %s "% (tb[0])
mycursor1.execute(sqlformula)
mydb1.commit()
```

File is exported successfully but is unable to import in cloud.
Getting an error :mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: File 'test.csv' could not be read

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the csv file as per your question you can do the following:

1. Upload the file into an EC2 Instance where AWS CLI is configured and you're able to reach your db.
2. As per AWS Documentation you can break the flat file into the following

   split -C 1024m -d test.csv test.part_

This will break the file into multiple parts lesser than 1 GB On Unix-like systems (including Linux).

3. Use the mysqlimport utility to load the flat files into Amazon RDS. In the example we tell mysqlimport to load all of the files named "test" with an extension starting with "part_". This is a convenient way to load all of the files created in the "split" example. Use the --compress option to minimize network traffic. The --fields-terminated-by=',' option is used for CSV files and the --local option specifies that the incoming data is located on the client. Without the --local option, the Amazon RDS DB instance looks for the data on the database host, so always specify the --local option.

For Linux:

```
mysqlimport --local \
    --compress \
    --user=username \
    --password \
    --host=hostname \
    --fields-terminated-by=',' Acme test.part_*
```

Here's the actual Documentation:
[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.AnySource.html][1]